# Why doesnt the query work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to find the name, pic and page_url of the pages which installed my application.

So I created this query:

```
SELECT pic, name, page_url FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page WHERE has_added_app = 1)
```

What's wrong? I understood that the "WHERE" has to be with indexable parameters - "page_id" is indexable parameter but "has_added_app" is not.. but I have to use it.. so how do I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 604: Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FQL_Tables thrown in /***/public_html/app/lib/facebook.php on line 495

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can't get this information.  A thread on the developer forum on facebook.com http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=237709

You could return the data in JSON format and include the `has_added_app`  You could then maybe use some funky Javascript to determine if its true or not.  No idea if this is possible though.

Or there is always the Old Rest Api [pages.getInfo](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.getinfo) or [pages.isAppAdded](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isAppAdded)

[Full Facebook FQL reference page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Comment: There is a way with FQL + PHP + graph api only?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a simple why of doing it I'm afraid

Comment: o.O? i did not understand you. :-)

Comment: @Luis - What?  I don't understand your comment. What is your question?

Comment: I want to find the name, pic, page_url of the pages which installed my app - how do i do it? without JS.. only php + graph api + fql..
i thougt another way - when the page installed my app - his id and his access_token will save in external DB (which i will open in my hosting plan) - can I do it maybe?

Comment: @Luis- That is the point I am trying to make.  I don't think it is possible to do it.

Comment: No way.. cant I take all of the pages which installed my app? or register them on external DB in the moment they register?